# GPUTimer as a separate class

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to create a class for GPU time measurements and using it inside my Cuda program, but somehow I can't get it to run properly. My class and header files look like this:

GPUTimer.h:

```
#ifndef GPUTIMER_H_
#define GPUTIMER_H_

class GPUTimer
{
    public:
        GPUTimer();
        virtual ~GPUTimer();

        void start_timer(cudaStream_t stream_id = 0);
        void stop_timer(cudaStream_t stream_id = 0);
        void print_elapsed_time();

    public:
        bool m_Started;
        bool m_Stopped;
        cudaEvent_t m_StartEvent;
        cudaEvent_t m_StopEvent;
};

#endif /* GPUTIMER_H_ */
```

GPUTimer.cpp:

```
#include "GPUTimer.h"
#include "kernels.h"

GPUTimer::GPUTimer()
{
    m_Started = false;
    m_Stopped = false;
}

GPUTimer::GPUTimer() : m_Started(false), m_Stopped(false)
{
    cudaEventCreate(&m_StartEvent); CUDA_CHECK;
    cudaEventCreate(&m_StopEvent);  CUDA_CHECK;
}

GPUTimer::~GPUTimer()
{
    cudaEventDestroy(m_StartEvent); CUDA_CHECK;
    cudaEventDestroy(m_StopEvent);  CUDA_CHECK;
}

// Start event timer
void GPUTimer::start_timer(cudaStream_t stream_id = 0)
{
    cudaEventRecord(m_StartEvent, stream_id); CUDA_CHECK;
    m_Started = true;
    m_Stopped = false;
}

// End event timer
void GPUTimer::stop_timer(cudaStream_t stream_id = 0)
{
   if(!m_Started)
   {
       std::cout << "Timer hasn't started yet. Please call start_timer() before!" << std::endl;
       return;
   }
   cudaEventRecord(m_StopEvent, stream_id); CUDA_CHECK;
   m_Started = false;
   m_Stopped = true;
}

// Print elapsed time
void GPUTimer::print_elapsed_time()
       {
           if(!m_Stopped)
           {
               std::cout << "Timer hasn't stopped yet. Please call stop_timer() before!" << std::endl;
               return;
           }
           cudaEventSynchronize(m_StopEvent);
           float elapsed_time = 0.0f;
           cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed_time, m_StartEvent, m_StopEvent);

           std::cout << "Elapsed GPU Time: " << elapsed_time         << " msec" << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Elapsed GPU Time: " << elapsed_time / 1000  << " secs" << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Elapsed GPU Time: " << elapsed_time / 60000 << " mins" << std::endl;
       }
```

Inside `kernels.h` I'm including `<cuda_runtime.h>`, but when I try to compile the program, it says that `cudaStream_t` has not been declared:

```
error: ‘cudaStream_t’ has not been declared
         void start_timer(cudaStream_t stream_id = 0);
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `#include <cuda_runtime.h>` (or `#include "kernels.h"` ) to your header file `GPUTimer.h`. Otherwise `cudaStream_t` is indeed not declared when the compiler looks at the code in the `GPUTimer.h` header file. Your header file should be self-sufficient and declare all types you are using by including the corresponding header files.

Regarding the comment: Default parameters are only allowed in the function declaration (i.e. header file) not in the definition (i.e. source file). This is a good thing, otherwise you might accidentally provide two different values.
So write

```
void GPUTimer::start_timer(cudaStream_t stream_id)
```

Comment: Great, that solved that error...but now I'm getting some errors regarding the default parameters for `start_timer()` and `stop_timer()`: ...cpp:23:54: error: default argument given for parameter 1 of ‘void GPUTimer::start_timer(cudaStream_t)’ [-fpermissive]
 void GPUTimer::start_timer(cudaStream_t stream_id = 0)

Comment: Search SO in the upper right hand corner of this page with "default argument given for parameter 1" and I think you'll find the answer to this second issue.